# Stata test if string contains same character

Tags: string, dataframe, loops, automation, stata

I want to automatically test if the string contains only one type of character, with the result in a true/false variable "check"

```
input str11 contactno 
"aaaaaaaaaaa"
"bbbbbbbbbbb"
"aaaaaaaaaab"
end
```

my attempt

```
gen check = .
//loop through dataset
local db =_N
forval x = 1/`db'{
dis as error "obs `x'"
//get first character in string
local f = substr(contactno, 1, 1) in `x' 
//loop through each character in string
capture drop check_*
forvalues i = 1/11 {
    quietly gen check_`i'=.
    local j = substr(contactno, `i', 1) in `x'

    //Tag characters that match
    if "`j'" == "`f'"  {
    local y = 1
    replace check_`i'= 1 in `x'
        } 
    else  {
    local y= 0
    replace check_`i'= 0 in `x'
    }
    
}
```

Expected results the first two observations should be true and the third false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in one line of code as follows:

1. Take the first character of `contactno`.
2. Find all instances of this character in `contactno` and replace with an empty string (i.e., "").
3. Test whether the resulting string is empty.

```
gen check = missing(subinstr(contactno,substr(contactno,1,1),"",.))


     +---------------------+
     |   contactno   check |
     |---------------------|
  1. | aaaaaaaaaaa       1 |
  2. | bbbbbbbbbbb       1 |
  3. | aaaaaaaaaab       0 |
     +---------------------+
```

So we are leveraging the fact that if all characters are not equal to the first character, then the string cannot contain only one (type of) character.

Comment: Very nice. This should be publishable somehow!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it.

```
clear 
input str11 contactno 
"aaaaaaaaaaa"
"bbbbbbbbbbb"
"aaaaaaaaaab"
end

gen long id = _n
save original_data, replace 
expand 11 
bysort id : gen character = substr(contactno, _n, 1)
bysort id (character) : gen byte OK = character[1] == character[_N]
drop character 
bysort id : keep if _n == 1 
merge 1:1 id using original_data 

list 

     +-------------------------------------+
     |   contactno   id   OK        _merge |
     |-------------------------------------|
  1. | aaaaaaaaaaa    1    1   Matched (3) |
  2. | bbbbbbbbbbb    2    1   Matched (3) |
  3. | aaaaaaaaaab    3    0   Matched (3) |
     +-------------------------------------+
```